# Interpreting hex dump of java class file

Tags: java, class, hex

I understand the structure of a java .class file, but when I want to interpret the raw hex data I get a bit lost.

This is a hex dump of a class file, excluding the header and constant pool.

[image: hex dump of class file]

I understand the header to be the magic number, minor_version and major_version. It seems the next value should be the access flags.

Which value would that be in this chart? 000000b0? I thought it would be a simple number not a hex value.

Which value is this_class, the index into the constant pool where the class details can be determined?

Comment: Please read the [JVM spec section on the class file format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html). At offset `0b` you're probably somewhere right in the middle of the constant pool. It's not possible to tell since you've cut off the first 16 bytes, which contains how many constant pool entries there are.

Comment: The constant pool is excluded in this example

Comment: If you start the dump at offset 000000b0, then you have *not* excluded the constant pool; you started right in the middle of it. If you want a real answer, you should post the entire dump, starting at offset zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `000000b0` is not part of the data. It's the memory address where the following 16 bytes are located.

The two-digit hex numbers are the actual data. Read them from left to right. Each row is in two groups of eight, purely to asist in working out memory addresses etc.

So to answer your question indirectly, you can work out where the access flags are by simply counting past the number of bytes used by the magic number, minor version and major version. The access flags will come next. Likewise, to find any other values (such as this_class), you have to work out what their offset is and look at that location in the data.

You say that you expected a "simple number not a hex vaue", but that doesn;t really make sense as hex values *are* simple numbers. They're simply represented in base-16 instead of base-10. There are plenty of resources online that will teach you how to convert between the two.

Comment: Thank you. So in this example, since magic, minor_version, major_version, and constant pool are not included, the access_flag is the value 04 if I understand correctly.

Comment: Assuming you've correctly excluded them, then I *think* you'll find the access flags occupy 2 bytes - so the 04 21 in your extract. IIRC they're held as a 16-bit uint. I'd strongly recommend you read the link that Erwin posted in a comment as all the information is in there. If there's anything in there you don't fully understand, you can always post a more specific question.